# jQuery .slideUp() sticking

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm having an issue when using the jQuery `slideUp()` method. I have a timer set to slide up a div over 1 second then display a paragraph. I have an h1 element in my div that is centered on the screen. The issue is when this h1 element reaches the top of the browser window the sliding animation stops and pauses for a moment before the h1 disappears. Is there a reason the sliding motion does not continue all the way to the top and animate the h1 sliding, or any way I can smooth it out? My code:

HTML

```
<div class="screen fact fact-1" id="screen-6">
    <div class="access-intro1 fact-intro fact-intro-1">
        <h1>ACCESS</h1>
    </div>
    <p class="fact-text fact-text1"><span class="big countUp">150</span</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.fact-text1 {
    display: none;
}

.access-intro1 {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}

.access-intro1 h1 {
    margin-top: 0;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

JS

```
window.setTimeout(accessTransition, 2500);
function accessTransition()
{
    $('.access-intro1').slideUp(1000);
    $('.fact-text1').css('display', 'inline-block');
    countUp();
}
```

Comment: do you have a fixed nav bar and therefore padding on the body ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jUqury` `slideUp()` function uses `overflow:none` and reduces the `height` of the element up to 0 with time, to create the effect of sliding it up close. And `overflow:none` evidently works on block elements and not table elements.

So remove the `display:table` from `.access-intro1` class and it will work just fine.

```
.access-intro1 {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display:table; /*remove it*/ 
}
```

**[CodePen Demo](http://codepen.io/rmrinmoy/pen/grexOW)**

Comment: Got it, thanks. I was using the 'display: table' to perform a vertical align but I can figure out a different way to do that.

Comment: Vertical align works with `inline-block` elements too, when there is a reference to vertically alignment. Or else you can try using `flexbox`.